# Open Server Error (ошибка)

Tags: phpmyadmin, openserver

Здравствуйте! При запуске PhpMyAdmin появляется ошибка:

---

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with
>   message  'Overloading of string functions using mbstring.func_overload
>   is not supported by phpseclib.' in
>   W:\modules\system\html\openserver\phpmyadmin\vendor\phpseclib\phpseclib\phpseclib\bootstrap.php:11
>   Stack trace: #0
>   W:\modules\system\html\openserver\phpmyadmin\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(66):
>   require() #1
>   W:\modules\system\html\openserver\phpmyadmin\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(56):
>   composerRequiref375fa87e2093d8f1c8134104c2ce8cd('decc78cc4436b12...',
>   'W:\modules\syst...') #2
>   W:\modules\system\html\openserver\phpmyadmin\vendor\autoload.php(7):
>   ComposerAutoloaderInitf375fa87e2093d8f1c8134104c2ce8cd::getLoader() #3
>   W:\modules\system\html\openserver\phpmyadmin\libraries\common.inc.php(85):
>   require_once('W:\modules\syst...') #4
>   W:\modules\system\html\openserver\phpmyadmin\index.php(20):
>   require_once('W:\modules\syst...') #5 {main} thrown in
>   W:\modules\system\html\openserver\phpmyadmin\vendor\phpseclib\phpseclib\phpseclib\bootstrap.php
>   on line 11

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/mbstring.overload.php

Answer (score 0):

Помогла только переустановка OpenServer

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/195428)

Comment: а ведь достаточно было поменять версию PHP

Comment: @slippyk как бы смешно это не выглядело - но является))

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решается путём добавления в конфигурацию Apach`а следующего кода:

```
<Directory "%sprogdir%/modules/system/html/openserver/phpmyadmin">
AllowOverride All
php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 0
</Directory>
```

Решение взято с форума OpenServer